# Change marker icon with matching id

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to change the color of an existing pin. I have 5 pins with id values running from 1-5. can I change the pin if it's say equal to 3. I tried something like the code below but can't quite get what I'm looking for. any help would be great.

```
if(marker.id == 3){
     this.marker.setIcon(myPin2);
}
```

Comment: Try this answer **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697284/google-api-multiple-markers-with-different-colours-depending-on-a-class/24697331#24697331**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create 1 array of type (restaurants,hotels) 
or set default value of validate

and try this code:

```
var marker_new = new Array();
var url = "";
switch (marker.id){
   case 1: break;
   case 2: break;
   case 3:url = "http://exampl.com/yellow.png";   
   case 4: break;
   case 5: break;    
}
marker_new[i] = google.maps.Marker({
                                 icon: url;
                                 position: place.geometry.location,
                                 map: map
                               });
```

or read more in: [How can I modify the markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949867/how-can-i-modify-the-markers/23951393#23951393)

Comment: this seems a little complex for the basic type of thing I need, all my pins are of the same type, seems a little over complicated to do a types array just for one out of 5 pins

Answer (score 1):

You can try my answer. It accurately worked for me.

```
    if(marker.id == 3){
         marker.setIcon(myPin2);
    }else{
        marker.setIcon(myPin1);
     }
```

If you need to know something else, I am here to help you. please don't forget to tell me if it worked for you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var myPin2 = new google.maps.MarkerImage('imgs/pin2.png');

if(marker.id == 3){
     this.marker.setIcon(myPin2);
}
```

Comment: I think it's the this. part that isn't working, not sure for the term to change the matching instance

Comment: The MarkerImage class is deprecated, you should use the [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) class instead