# Google maps image overlay and multicolored markers - how to combine code?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two sample codes:

1. Map: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Pit3BhPYj4Y0xjMnNabXRicTg/view
2. Markers: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Pit3BhPYj4Z2x5TElQb25kcHc/view

What I want to do is to place markers (from file 2) onto the map (1) (that has overlaid image).

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: in your initialize function in file 1, loop over the markers array, creating a new marker for each.

Comment: @Duncan thanks for Your answer. Unfortunately I still can't figure it out. Can You give me an example of file 1 with just two (different colored) markers?

Answer (score 0):

Fllow this answer : [Change marker icon with matching id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801060/change-marker-icon-with-matching-id/29801479#29801479)

```
var marker_new = new Array();
var url = "";
switch (marker.id){
   case 1: break;
   case 2: break;
   case 3:url = "http://exampl.com/yellow.png";   
   case 4: break;
   case 5: break;    
}
marker_new[i] = google.maps.Marker({
                                 icon: url;
                                 position: place.geometry.location,
                                 map: map
                               });
```

**Update**
example: http://jsfiddle.net/uL2Lshu6/7/

Comment: Thanks for Your answer @HoangHieu. Unfortunately I still don't know how to do it. Not that I'm lazy (spend few days on searching before post question here) I just have lack of skills. Maybe You can prepare an example of file 1 with just two (different colored) markers? i'll be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know where and how to add it to my 1. Map file.