# How to set different color of markers on google maps?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to set a different color marker depending on the type that it gets from my database. For example the type is FIRE and I want the marker to be color red. Is it possible?

Here is my maps.html

```
 (function(){

            var map,marker,latlng,bounds,infowin;
            /* initial locations for map */
            var _lat=14.676;
            var _lng=121.0437;



            function showMap(){
                /* set the default initial location */
                latlng={ lat: _lat, lng: _lng };

                bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                infowin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                /* invoke the map */
                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
                   center:latlng,
                   zoom: 10
                });

                /* show the initial marker */
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position:latlng,
               map: map,
               title: 'Hello World!'
            });




                bounds.extend( marker.position );


                /* jQuery */
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'get.php',
                    data: {'ajax':true },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function( data, status ){
                        $.each( data, function( i,item ){
                            /* add a marker for each location in response data */ 
                            addMarker( item.lat, item.lng, item.username);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                    }
                });                 
            }

            /* simple function just to add a new marker */
            function addMarker(lat,lng,title){
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({/* Cast the returned data as floats using parseFloat() */
                   position:{ lat:parseFloat( lat ), lng:parseFloat( lng ) },
                   map:map,
                   title:title

                });

                google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(event){
                    infowin.setContent(this.title);
                    infowin.open(map,this);
                    infowin.setPosition(this.position);
                }.bind( marker ));

                bounds.extend( marker.position );
                map.fitBounds( bounds );
            }


            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', showMap, false );
        }());
    </script>
    <style>
        html, html body, #map{ height:100%; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='map'></div>

</body>
```

Here is my get.php where I get the data from the database.

```
$mysql ="SELECT lat,lng,username,type FROM `tbl_coordinates`";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $mysql);
if (!empty($result))
{

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $latlng[] = array(
    'lat' => $row['lat'], 
    'lng' => $row['lng'],
    'username' => $row['username'],
    'type' => $row['type'],



     );

   }
   }

    mysqli_close($connect);

   header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
   echo json_encode($latlng);
   ?>
```

Comment: are you working on which version's google api ?

Comment: google maps api v3

Comment: Please search before ask:: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697284/google-api-multiple-markers-with-different-colours-depending-on-a-class/24697331#24697331

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I modify the markers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949867/how-can-i-modify-the-markers)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one more parameter `icon` in below functions,

```
 /* show the initial marker */
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position:latlng,
           map: map,
           title: 'Hello World!',
           icon: 'marker1.png' // path of your icon image. 
        });
```

And visit this link :- http://www.benjaminkeen.com/google-maps-coloured-markers/ from this link you can download all the markers. So put this marker's image in your directory and give path to that image in `icon` parameter. 
This is the easiest way of adding other marker in google map.

**EDIT :**

So for that you have to put condition's like if it's color is red then put red icon. if flood than flood's icon.

if you got value in `$color = 'red'`; from php
than in javascript put it like this,

```
var color = <?php echo $color; ?>
```

then check using color that,

```
if(color == 'red')
{
         icon: 'red.png'
}
if(color == 'blue')
{
         icon: 'flood.jpg'          
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bhavin! But what about when I got another type like FLOOD and I want the marker to be set as color blue?

Comment: you can make image of FLOOD etc. in photoshop or any other tools. and put that image in the directory of images and give path of that image to icon parameter. simple :)

Comment: Nope, not like that. What I want is I set the type and it automatically change the color of the marker. For example the type that came from my database is FLOOD, and I want the marker to be automatically set to color blue because the TYPE it gets from my database is FLOOD.

Comment: Can you help me how can I create a condition like that? Thanks.

Comment: Brother where will I put that code of yours? Can you try put it on the code I post?