# Update google maps marker icon with listener

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have written some code using the google maps API. When the user clicks anywhere on the map, it creates a marker in this place and an infoWindow opens allowing them to select whether this marker is type "A" or type "B". I would like the icon to update when the user clicks "Save" on this InfoWindow.

HTML :

```
<div id="form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><input type='text' id='name' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address:</td>
      <td><input type='text' id='address' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type:</td>
      <td><select id='type'> +
                  <option value='A' SELECTED>A</option>
                  <option value='B'>B</option>
          </select> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type='button' value='Save' onclick='saveData()' /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Javascript initialisation :

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: document.getElementById('form')
});

messagewindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: document.getElementById('message')
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    document.getElementById('form').style.display = "block";
  });
});
```

But I am not sure what to put into my saveData() method in order to update the icon used for the marker created. Is this possible??

```
function saveData() {
 marker.update.setIcon("../images/A.png);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949867/how-can-i-modify-the-markers/23951393#23951393

Comment: `marker.update` what is that? `marker.setIcon(...)` should work. Your code is incomplete. Where do you define the `marker` variable? Where is your `saveData` function? etc. If you need more help, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: @MrUpsidown The marker variable is defined in the listener definition.

Comment: No, it's not...

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to keep a reference to the last marker added to the map, and use that to access the marker and change its icon.

in the global scope:

```
var lastmarker;
```

in your click listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    lastmarker = marker;
    document.getElementById('form').style.display = "block";
  });
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click');
});
```

In  your saveData function:

```
function saveData() {
  if (lastmarker && lastmarker.getIcon) {
    var iconUrl = "https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker"+$("#type").val()+".png";
    lastmarker.setIcon(iconUrl);
  }
}
```

[Proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/e56zxn4h/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var lastmarker;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: document.getElementById('form')
  });

  messagewindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: document.getElementById('message')
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      lastmarker = marker;
      document.getElementById('form').style.display = "block";
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function saveData() {
  if (lastmarker && lastmarker.getIcon) {
    var iconUrl = "https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + $("#type").val() + ".png";
    lastmarker.setIcon(iconUrl);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

#form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><input type='text' id='name' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address:</td>
      <td><input type='text' id='address' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type:</td>
      <td>
        <select id='type'>
          <option value='A' SELECTED>A</option>
          <option value='B'>B</option>
          <option value='C'>C</option>
          <option value='D'>D</option>
          <option value='E'>E</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type='button' value='Save' onclick='saveData()' /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```